# Is there an automatic documentation for SignalR similar to the Web API Help Page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr, signalr-2

In an ASP.NET Web API project, we can create [Help Page](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages) which automatically generates documentation for all of the Web APIs in the project.

Can we do the same thing for SignalR?

Comment: Did you ever find anything?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not.